# Scala's choice in implementing Option

Tags: scala

How it's done in Scala:

```
  sealed trait Option[+A] {
    def get: A
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
      if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
  }
  object None extends Option[Nothing] {
    def isEmpty = true
    def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
  }
  case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] {
    def isEmpty = false
    def get = x
  }
```

How I would assume it in OOP world:

```
  sealed trait Option[+A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
  }
  object None extends Option[Nothing] {
    def map[B](f: Nothing => B): Option[B] = this
  }
  case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = Some(f(get))
  }
```

What's wrong with the latter?

[Functional programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) is using `match` in `Option[A]` trait, which is the third way (looks like Haskell, but why?) Why not utilize subtype polymorphism?

**UPDATE**: Third way I mentioned:

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  }
}
object None extends Option[Nothing] {
}
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A] {
}
```

Comment: It's one facet of the expression problem, in this case I would personally go with `match` because: a.) You won't have any other implementations of that trait (both because that's the logic behind that data type, but also because of the second point below); subtype polymorphism is useful when you can't anticipate all implementations up front. b.) It's sealed, so you'll get exhaustive pattern matching warnings/errors. Scala implementation *probably* uses the flag for speed, bool flag check is fast and has no indirection.

Comment: You may also be interested in scalaz's `Maybe` implementation:
https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/83e1b85ee4b18df016486515dfeb725c6a41a0fd/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Maybe.scala

And the according discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/sfnDnISpjPw/5gm8hjIlsS8J

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you intended to, but you left out the declarations of `isEmpty` and `get`, which are needed by anyone that wants to check the contents of an arbitrary `Option` without needing to downcast to `Some`. Since both of these methods need to be defined by both subclasses, and since `map` can be defined in terms of them, I think the reasoning was that it would be better to define `map` in one place leveraging the subclass implementations of the other methods, rather than defining `map` in three places.

Comment: `isEmpty` would be defined as in Scala if I needed it, which I don't as long as I stay within functional paradigm. Same for `get`, do I really need `get` for `None`? I would use `getOrElse` or `orElse`.

Comment: You can check the content of an `Option` with pattern matching. I think this should be the preferred way in Scala. The scalaz developers even build a replacement for `Option` called `Maybe` without the unsafe `get`.

Comment: isEmpty is needed for use cases where Option is treated like a collection of zero or one elements. The problem with requiring pattern matching is that you would then be making an implicit instanceof and cast mandatory. It's also a lot more verbose for something that could be handled with a single `if` expression.

Comment: `if(isEmpty) default_val else get` vs `this match { None => default_val; Some(v) => v }`. In the former case you have up to 2 polymorphic calls (`isEmpty`, `get`), the latter probably uses `instanceOf` behind the scene, but only once. Cast is free I presume. Of course in real life it would be much shorter `x getOrElse default_val`

Comment: If you'd like to argue that the design should change, you'll have to take it up with Martin Odersky, but I don't think you'll get very far. I'm just explaining what I think the reasoning was.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that since scala support both functional and imperative and it aiming java programs, this is one of the stuff that make them fill more comfortable.
From java programmer

```
val opt: Option[String] = ???
if (!opt.isEmpty) {
  //do something with opt.get
} else {
  //do some default...
}
```

may be more understandable than functional way (even with getOrElse).

@Victor Moroz wrote in one of the comments about using pattern matching instead of the `this match { None => default_val; Some(v) => v }`
This in addition to be harder to read by programmer new to the functional world, will cost much more, since Option is intended to be use a lot, and instanceOf cost more than a simple if.

Comment: `instanceOf` costs more than polymorphic call `isEmpty`? Even two of them (including `get`)? I doubt it, they should be equal. Agree about Java argument though, but my guess is Java programmers won't use `Option`, there are `null` and `NullPointerException` for them. Maybe my question is wrong, not why Scala does it this way, but how it should be done and should I follow Scala's path, or one of two others.