# Why Scala library shuns dynamic binding?

Tags: scala, try-catch, either

If I were writing the library I would habitually write Option like this:

```
abstract class Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
}

case object None extends Option[Nothing] {
  override def map[B](f: Nothing => B): Option[B] = None
}

case class Some[+A](a: A) extends Option[A] {
  override def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = new Some(f(a))
}
```

Notice using polymorphism for `map` implementation. However, the real implementation of map is fully in the Option class and it looks like this:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
    if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```

I claim my implementation is cleaner (see the advantages of polymorphism elsewhere) and is probably faster. In `Either` type matching is used instead of `if` in similar cases, reminding me of the `switch` statements you see C people use when they come to Java. Interestingly, the analogous implementation in `Try` follows my OOP school. So I would guess a shorter solution was selected in `Option`. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: Basically the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982010/scalas-choice-in-implementing-option

Answer (score 3):

1. `Option` is `sealed` abstract class, so it's not a target for OOP-style polymorphism, as you not allowed to extend it's with your class.
2. Most of method implementations are based on methods `get` and `isEmpty`, those are only two defined outside of `Option` keeping sources for `None` and `Some` ridiculously small. So if you want to see how `flatMap` or `collect` are implemented you need not to switch from one part of source to another. I think, this makes that source much more readable.
3. Those little functions are nice candidates for JIT's inline. Method that need to be dispatched could be inlined only via unsafe optimization, which of course could rarely occurs in context where `Option` is really needed. So i doubt your implementation is really faster.
4. There is much said about `Functional` vs `OOP` style in link, supplied by @m-z and in internets all around. So i'll keep out of that particular holy war.

Comment: The point #1 is incorrect - even without additional subtypes the Option is already polymorphic with its two subtypes. The point #2 is agreeable. As to #3, assuming inlining, still both `get` and `isEmpty` are dynamically bound and together will be twice slower than the single dynamic invocation in my implementation. W.r.t. #4 I believe there is nothing non-FP in my implementation.

Comment: @jacool in #1 I specialized `OOP-style` polymorphism which is radically differs with functional polymorphism, this declaration is equivalent of `data Option a = Some a | None` of ML family. So you never should think about it as some abstract type, it's very concrete type with two concrete alternatives

Comment: @jacool in #3 You should really do measurements before saying _"twice slower"_. Methods as simple as `return <field>` or `return <constant>` exeptionally nice simplified during JVM's JIT-compilation, and while compiler seeing there is two super-simple methods and bunch of methods that are not needed for runtime dispatch, it could super-simplify any complex expression using `Option` type

Comment: @jacool About #4 - I personally think your beliefs are somewhat wrong, but it's not the place to discuss things like that

Comment: @jacool As anyone with OOP background you should know why [microbenchmarks are evil](https://www.google.ru/webhp?#q=microbenchmarks+are+evil)